# call function in jQuery with out element or event

Tags: php, jquery

I want to call the function **my ()** which Displayed under,

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var showing = {


    apper: function my () {

        $("#element").click(function (e) {//>>>>>>>>>>>>This function, which I want to call it.

            e.preventDefault(); 
            var f = document.forms["ff"]["p_1"].value;
             if(f=="1234")


            $("#content").modal({
                overlayId: 'overlay',
                containerId: 'container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: showing.open,
                onClose: showing.close
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("#content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $("#data", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 20; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#data", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this; 
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
            500,
            function () {
                self.close(); 
            }
        );
    }
};

showing.apper();

});
```

Like this `onclick="my();"` In the following code,

```
 <form  id="ff" name="l"  method="POST" action="dd.html" >           
          <input id="p_1"   name="p_1"/>
          <input id="p_2" name="p_2"/>
        <input type="submit"  id="" onclick="my();" />  //<<<<<<< I want to call here.
    </form>
```

Because if the call was by **id** That it names **#element**,
The action of form  doesn't work.

Comment: what you are tring to make with the `showing` variable?

Comment: where is the `#element` ?

Comment: `showing.apper(); `I want to show the div **content** in the dialog form, Instead of**alelrt**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind onclick and also call onclick to perform some operation.
just do this instead

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function callOperation(){
        alert($("#p_1").val());
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <form  id="ff" name="l"  method="POST" action="dd.html" >           
      <input type="text" id="p_1" name="p_1"/>
      <input type="text" id="p_2" name="p_2"/>
      <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="callOperation();"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7GVAkcEflojUmB5Tl9ax)